# How to get routing working in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on the following [react project](https://github.com/ipatch/crj-frontend), and am trying to get the relative links in the navbar to work properly.  However, when I click on *About Me* I get the following response,

```
Cannot GET /about
```

The code I am working with looks like the following,

**App.js**

```
// This component handles the App template used on every page.
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Header from './common/Header';
import NavBar from './common/navbar';
import Router from 'react-router';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';

var navbar = {};
navbar.brand = {linkTo: "http://chrisrjones.com", text: "chrisrjones.com"};
navbar.links = [
  // <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link>
    {linkTo: "/about", text: "About Me"},
    {linkTo: "#", text: "Contact"},
    {dropdown: true, text: "Contribute", links: [
        {linkTo: "#", text: "Sign Up"},
        {linkTo: "#", text: "Login"}
    ]}
];

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <NavBar {...navbar}/>
                <Header/>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

Also, to get an idea of what the navbar code looks like you can check out [this codepen](http://codepen.io/zhaozhiming/pen/LNGyvR) that I referenced for the navbar code in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking inside your Navbar component I found one things that is may be causing this issue, there are two approach for that:

- Using href, you should use absolute path, not relative
- Use Link from react-router instead of 'a':

Example approach 1:

```
<a className="navbar-brand" href={ 'http://www.absolutepath.com' + this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text}</a>
```

Example approach 2:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'

<Link to={ this.props.linkTo }>
  <span className="navbar-brand">{this.props.text}</span>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `server.js`, redirect all routes requests to the root /index.html file (ignoring file requests):

```
app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  const filename = path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html')
  compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
    res.set('content-type', 'text/html')
    res.send(result)
    res.end()
  })
})
```